# Can't find anything because search is broken

Tags: bug, search

See, I can't find *anything* (although tag searches worked):

> [image]

Then the whole site died when I tried to reproduce this problem on MSE:

> [image]

If the site is offline, how did I ask this question?

Comment: I double this issue

Comment: [cross-site duplicate at MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365626/839601)

Answer (score 2):

Search is working as usual again.

I can find [everything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=everything)!